# Which is more efficient way to extract latest records from table in Snowflake: RANK function or Filter rows with Max updated timestamp using Self Join

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, query-optimization, real-time, cdc

Use Case: Real-Time Change Data Capture from Source Table into Snowflake Stream. Then consuming the Stream using a Task to merge (INSERT/UPDATE) change records into the Target Table at regular intervals.

End Result: Target table as exact replica of the source table.

Problem Statement: In a scenario where a record with Primary key field (say "ID" ) has more than one (multiple) updates in the source table, it makes sense to extract only the most recent modified record i.e. record with max(updated timestamp) for each "ID" from the change Stream and execute UPDATE into the target table.
There could be two approaches to extract only the latest records for all distinct "ID"s from the source:

1. Using RANK WINDOW function

   ```
   select * from (

   select *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY updated_timestamp desc) as rnk

   from STREAM

   ) X

   where rnk = 1
   ```
2. Using SubQuery and Self Join

   ```
   select A.*

   from STREAM A

   join (select ID, max(updated_timestamp) AS max_updated_timestamp

   from STREAM B

   GROUP ID

   ) B

   ON A.ID = B.ID

   AND A.updated_timestamp = B.max_updated_timestamp
   ```

Which approach will be more efficient 1 OR 2 for frequently updating large data streams?

Tried both logics for sample dataset and observed that logic with RANK function scans less partitions as compared to the logic with self join. Wanted to understand which logic would take less time when used on a huge dataset.

Comment: Step wise Description of the Data Pipeline:
1. Extracting row level changes from Source Table (DynamoDB) using Kinesis Data Stream and creating json logs with record "New Image" and "Old Image".
2. Coping these json logs using pipe into Snowflake "Staging Table". So, the staging table has a new entry of each change that happens into the source record i.e. every INSERT and UPDATE will be stored as a row with eventName flag "INSERT" or "MODIFY".
3. Creating a Stream on top of "Staging Table" to detect new changes and executing a task with MERGE to update/insert the changes to Target Table.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> In a scenario where a record with Primary key field (say "ID" ) has more than one (multiple) updates in the source table, it makes sense to extract only the most recent modified record

But it doesn't make sense because a standard stream returns the DELTA:

```
create or replace table table_stream_test (id number, v varchar, z varchar ) as
    select * from values (1,'Gokhan','Test'),(2,'Joe','Test');

create or replace stream stream_test on table table_stream_test;
    
-- two separate updates on the same row!
update table_stream_test set v = 'Jack' where id = 1;
update table_stream_test set z = 'Prod' where id = 1;
    
select * from stream_test; -- returns 2 rows (1 INSERT + 1 DELETE, the changes are combined)

-- reverting the changes:
update table_stream_test set v = 'Gokhan' where id = 1;
update table_stream_test set z = 'Test' where id = 1;
    
select * from stream_test; -- returns 0 rows
```

In short, you don't need to extract the most recent modified record. The stream will return the delta to apply.

Comment: This is true if the source table is being upserted but if the source table only contains newly inserted data and nothing is updated ever, it is possible to have multiple records for the same row during the offset period, meaning you have to choose one.

Comment: @DeanFlinter based on the question, their target is to have an "exact replica" of the source table, ID column is the primary key (so no duplicates) and they are looking for a solution to pick the latest update (which is not needed). If there are multiple rows with the same ID, inserting only one of them will not help them to have an exact replica ;)

Comment: all true normally but it seems, based on the comment they've added to the OP, the source table is not a Snowflake table and the stream is actually capturing CDC logs from the source table. Looks like insert only data so this is possible. A similar situation can be simulated in Snowflake though if your source table is a snowpipe target

Answer (score 1):

In terms of streams and tasks, we use a QUALIFY rank statement, just to have a little less code

```
SELECT * FROM stream
QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY updated_timestamp desc)=1
```

I haven't tried using MAX style on a stream so can't say if it would be more efficient but previously I did have a view where initially we used a window function but as the data grew, this became slower and slower. A MAX style system turned out to be faster in that case so we switched to that

Comment: I am at the point of choosing either ranking over a partition or using a max update timestamp self-join.  It is very helpful to know that self join will be better in the long term, thanks.  I am not using a stream.  Could you explain ELI5 why Qualify is used here and how it helps?

Comment: @SteveHibbert for our stream there was a possibility of 2 or more inserts for the same ID and we wanted the latest one. QUALIFY allows you to evaluate the result of the RANK function in the same line, without having to wrap the entire statement and put a WHERE rank=1 clause after it. Just neater really

Comment: @SteveHibbert also I should note that the relatively new MAX_BY function performs even better than a MAX with self join as the join is not required. Might not be suitable for your use case but just letting you know

Comment: Will investigate, thanks @Dean Flinter!